# How can I use MAX and LIMIT together in MySQL

Tags: mysql, limit, max

I have a table with the following structure:

## ID | Color

1 | red
2 | blue
3 | yellow
8 | purple
10| green
.
.
.
100|yellow

I would like to be able to grab the MAX ID value for the first 5 rows.

For example, I would like to do something like so:
Select MAX(ID) From Table LIMIT 5

Hoping this would return the value 10

But, MySQL keeps returning 100...its like MySQL does not even see the LIMIT clause.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It sounds like you want to select the top 5 records (ordered by ID) and then get the highest value of that group?  If so:

```
SELECT
    MAX(ID)
FROM
    ( 
         SELECT ID 
         FROM YourTable
         ORDER BY ID
         LIMIT 5
    ) as T1
```

Comment: you probably don't need to "select *" ; only "select id" should be enough ? (I am not sure it does, but maybe selecting only the field(s) you need could decrease the amout memory required -- which is always nice)

Comment: Yes, this should be `SELECT ID`

Comment: But this internally creates a new table, when we just need the max. I'm temped to say that this is as slow as selecting the sorted rows with `LIMIT` and computing the max outside SQL.

Answer (score 12):

There is better way to do this than subselect:

```
SELECT id FROM table LIMIT 4,1
```

Get one row but skip 4 first.. 
Add 'order by id' if this is MyISAM table.

Comment: This works if you know how many rows there are. If you exceed the row count, the query returns NULL. I needed this for batch purposes, but the max version is more suitable in my case.

Comment: Nice! but will not work in case there are 4 instead of 5 records

Answer (score 0):

Use a subselect:

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM (SELECT id FROM table LIMIT 5);
```

That might not quite be valid SQL, but that should give you a general idea.

Comment: Not valid SQL.  You need an alias on each derived table + you should have an order-by so you get "defined" results.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a table with the following structure

```
ID | Color

1 | red
2 | blue
3 | yellow
8 | purple
10| green
.
.
.
100|yellow
```

The MAX ID value for the first 5 (AUTO_INCREMENT?) values is 5.
Btw, the MAX ID value for the first 6 values is 6. And 100 for all values.
Best regards.